# Android NDK r5 on Ubuntu - Cannot compile

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk

I cannot build with NDK r5 on Ubuntu 9.10 (or 9.04). Gives me the following
error (GLIBC 2.11 not found).

```
$ /home/android-ndk-r5/ndk-build  V=1

/home/android-ndk-r5/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/
linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6:
version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /home/android-ndk-r5/
toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-
linux-androideabi-gcc)
```

What do I need to install - can someone point me to the relevant apt-
get install command ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://codetrips.blogspot.com/2010/12/latest-update-for-android-sdk-breaks.html (which I found via this page: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1640029)